# If $X$ and $Y$ are normally distributed random variables with the same variance, what kind of distribution their substraction follows?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

Let $X \sim N(\mu_1, \sigma^2)$ and $Y \sim N(\mu_2, \sigma^2)$. I find the distribution of $X - Y$. I suspect that $X - Y \sim N(\mu_1 - \mu_2, \sigma^2)$. Indeed,

$\mu_{x-y} = \mu_x - \mu_y = \mu_1 - \mu_2$.

but I don't know how to prove that $\sigma^2_{X-Y} = \sigma^2$. I think the covariance must be zero, but the exercise doesn't say that the variables are independent. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: You can say nothing about the distribution of $X-Y$ without some extra assumption.

Comment: If the problem says nothing about their independence, then one case is to consider is $X-\mu_1 = Y-\mu_2$ in which case $-Y=\mu_1-\mu_2$ and the variance would vanish (constant rv). By contrast, if they're independent then their variances add: https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat500/book/export/html/572. So there's really not too much to say without conditions on their independence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some info on the *joint* distribution of $X,Y$ to describe the distribution of $X-Y$.  You cannot generally conclude $X-Y$ is normally distributed (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent#A_symmetric_example) for counterexample).  On the other hand, if $X,Y$ are jointly bivariate normal, then any linear combination of $X,Y$ is normal.

Without info on the joint distribution, we can say that for constants $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$, and $X\sim N(\mu_1,\sigma^2_1)$,$Y\sim N(\mu_2,\sigma^2_2),$

$$E[aX+bY]=a\mu_1+b\mu_2,\\ \text{Var}(aX+bY)=a^2\sigma^2_1+b^2\sigma^2_2+2ab\text{Cov}(X,Y).$$